# Can (and how does) Django serve twisted as a wsgi application?

Tags: django, twisted, wsgi

When answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19720766/173773), I figured out how to properly serve django as a wsgi application, using the twisted wsgi resource.

Is the reverse doable? Can Django serve wsgi applications, and, more specifically, how does one serve twisted as a wsgi application under Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisted is not a WSGI application; it's an engine for exposing objects to the network.  If you imagine a stack of technologies serving your web site, Twisted is squarely below Django in the stack.  Asking how to serve Twisted from within Django is a bit like asking how to serve Linux from within Django.

You may, however, be interested in [Crochet](http://blog.futurefoundries.com/2013/10/announcing-crochet-v10-use-twisted.html), which provides an easy-to-use, convenience layer for calling Twisted APIs from within Django code, among other things.